# I have an error saying 'Property 'strCategory' does not exist on type 'never'. i don't inderstand

Tags: html, angular, typescript, api, server

[I have an error saying 'Property 'strCategory' does not exist on type 'never'. i don't inderstand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19aS8.png)

Comment: Show your code. Never type is a value that never returns. My guess is you have an error somewhere

Answer (score 0):

1 - You must define an **interface** for the **Array**.

2 - Need to share the Stackblitz link to check what the **return** function.

3 - The **Never** type is used when you are sure that something is never going to occur. Source : [Source](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/typescript/typescript-never)